# Prevent mainframe in CWinAppEx derived application from opening on LoadFrame()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I a MFC SDI application that is derived from CWinAppEx. In its `InitInstance()` method, the mainframe object is created manually like this:

```
auto mainframe = new CMainFrame();
mainframe->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME);
m_pMainWnd = mainframe;
```

As soon as `LoadFrame` is called, the mainframe window appears. I want to prevent this from happening, as I need to display some dialogs before the mainframe is shown.

How can I prevent the mainframe window from appearing?

Comment: Can't you display the dialogs in `InitInstance()` *before* `LoadFrame()` is called?

Comment: The dialogs I need to display unfortunatly rely on some data that is loaded during the mainframe initialization. Legacy application...

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in this  [MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/257527fe-1345-499d-bece-7581ba6d2e7a/).

For brevity:
Create the mainframe window and set `m_bLoadWindowPlacement = false` before calling `LoadFrame` like this:

```
auto mainframe = new CMainFrame();
m_bLoadWindowPlacement = false;
mainframe->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME);
m_pMainWnd = mainframe;
```